# Breeze/Angular: How to select Enum type in html?

Tags: angularjs, enums, breeze

I know Breeze is supporting enum type now and I can get enum type show in html without problem. However, I couldn't figure out how to edit this field in client.

For example:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public SexTypes SexType { get; set; }
}

public enum SexTypes
{
    Male, Female
}
```

I want to use select tag to choose a sex type like

```
<select ng-model="student.sexType" ng-options="g for g in sexTypes"></select>
```

When I looked at metadata (via api/breeze/metadata), I do see my enum type as

```
enumType: {
    name: "SexTypes",
    isFlags: "false",
    underlyingType: "Int32",
    member: [
        {
            name: "Male",
            value: "0"
        },
        {
            name: "Female",
            value: "1"
        }
    ]
},
```

Now, the question is how do I populate `$scope.sexTypes` in my controller?

Answer (score 0):

If the metadata is returned as you have explained the binding for the select would be

```
<select ng-model="student.sexType" ng-options="g.name for g.value in enumType.member"></select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. However, I couldn't get it work. Two questions: 1. in ng-options you use enumType, how does it get populated or connected in $scope? 2. How to you get a specific enumType? I only show one enumType in question. There are usually more than one.

Comment: Not sure how you get metadata for the enum using api. If Breeze has an method for that, get that data and assign it to scope.If you have the enum metadata yo can select the enum to use based enumType.name filtering.

Comment: Well, I got the metadata by manually entering something like "http://localhost:1476/api/Breeze/metadata" in browser only to verify that the enum types are included in the metadata. My real question is how to access it from my controller? I couldn't find any example how to get to enumType in breeze.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Breeze supports Enum types in the way that you expect.

When Breeze reads the metadata, it sees that `Student.sexType` is an enum property and that the enum name is `SexType`. It records both facts in the data property metadata.

```
var property = manager.metdataStore.getEntityType('Student').getDataProperty('sexType');
console.log(property.enumType); // "Edm.Self.Color"
console.log(property.dataType.name): // "String"
```

But that's all that it "knows". The Breeze client `MetadataStore` ignores the `SexType` definition in the metadata from the server. It sets the `DataType` of the `Student.sexType` property to "String" because it expects the client to get and set the property with the enum's string name. And that's about it all it does

If you want to populate the dropdown with the enum values you'll have to make a list of them yourself and expose that list through the parent ViewModel (aka "controller" in ng-speak). You can either hardcode them or fish them out of the metadata stream that arrived from the server.

Breeze could ... and perhaps should ... capture the enum type and its values in the `MetadataStore`. I could offer an Enum Validator to detect when you set the property to other than one of the enum choices.

Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, it does neither of these things at the present time (v.1.4.5).

I think you have a worthy cause. I encourage you to express your interest in this subject on the [Breeze User Voice](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions).

Comment: Actually, this kind of data is already available in metadata as shown above. Is there a way to get it out on client?

Comment: You can fish it out of the incoming metadata JSON object ("the raw metadata"). See the `MetadataStore.fetchMetadata` API http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/MetadataStore.html#method_fetchMetadata

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround in the meantime, you could create global "enums" from your metadata like this:

```
manager.fetchMetadata()
    .then(function (data) {

        // extract all enums als global objects
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(data.schema.enumType, function (c) {
            window[c.name] = {};
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(c.member, function (m) {
                window[c.name][m.name] = m.value;
            });
        });

});
```

So if you had an enum called "SexType", you would now have a global object that you can call:

```
var gender = SexType.Female; //returns the value as defined in the server side enum
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it.

## Step 1

Configure my server controller to return enums from url like **~/api/breeze/enums?type={0}**.

## Step 2

Create the dataContext provider.

```
.provider("dataContext", [function () {
    var url = "/api/breeze";

    function context() {
        this.manager = new window.breeze.EntityManager(url);
    }

    context.prototype.query = function (entitySet) {
        return new window.breeze.EntityQuery(entitySet).using(this.manager);
    };

    context.prototype.saveChanges = function () {
        return this.manager.saveChanges();
    };

    this.$get = function () {
        return new context();
    };
}])
```

## Step 3

Create the myEntitySet directive.

```
.directive("myEntitySet", ["dataContext", function (dataContext) {
    return {
        scope: true,
        restrict: "A",
        controller: ["$scope", function ($scope) {
            $scope.items = [];
        }],
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            dataContext.query($attrs.myEntitySet)
                .execute()
                .then(function (data) {
                    $scope.items = data.results;
                    $scope.$apply();
                });
        }
    };
}])
```

## Step 4

Use the myEntitySet directive:

```
<select my-entity-set="Enums?type=ProductType"
    ng-model="item.Type"
    ng-options="c.Name as c.Name for c in items | orderBy:'Name':true">
</select>
```